# Do not pass tests

Tags: jmeter

while running all the tests at the same time, the tests take a long time to process and fail bad request.
If you run the same you individually, then everything is fine, the tests pass. What could be the problem, tell me please 
https://prnt.sc/p4pagc

In logs writes it:

`019-09-11 15:06:08,632 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-09-11 15:06:08,634 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-09-11 15:06:08,640 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-09-11 15:06:08,770 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : BILLING-API
2019-09-11 15:06:08,771 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group BILLING-API.
2019-09-11 15:06:08,771 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-09-11 15:06:08,771 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-09-11 15:06:08,772 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-09-11 15:06:08,773 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-09-11 15:06:08,789 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: BILLING-API 1-1
2019-09-11 15:06:38,861 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: BILLING-API 1-1
2019-09-11 15:06:38,861 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: BILLING-API 1-1
2019-09-11 15:06:38,861 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-09-11 15:06:38,862 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)`

Comment: with how many threads you are starting you test?

Comment: everything @Zohair

Comment: when you run 10 tests, everything is fine. The launch price is already 20, they are processed for a long time and as a result they give an error bad request. After one test fails, you have to rebuild the environment. I tried with the timer did not help @Zohair

Comment: The application that you are trying to test, is it hosted on the server or some local machine?

Comment: on the server @Zohair

Comment: What have you give the ramp up time?

Comment: add 100 threads and ramp up time 60, then try your test.

Comment: Tests are executed, but then an error appears. If these tests run separately or in a small "bundle", then they pass  https://prnt.sc/p4u91b @Zohair

Comment: It's a problem with the server where application is hosted, as the server is not accommodating the large thread simulation and the request are getting choke. Try testing another application online and check the behavior of that application.

Comment: why then the delay between requests does not help? @Zohair

Comment: It was for troubleshooting purpose if you put the ramp up time 180 then it will execute more better. Try once.

Comment: set such values ​​did not help https://prnt.sc/p5849w @Zohair